# Ajax success callback in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Hi want to implement ajax in my ruby on rails tutorials and the controller will return an object on handling the ajax request. I dont know to handle the response in my javascript file.
I want to update some div based on object returned in javascript file.

Here is what I have written in my showcomments.js.erb

```
$('.show_comment').bind('ajax:success', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr')="Something here from the object returned");
});
```

My link where ajax call is called is via this line of code

```
 <td><%= link_to 'Show Comment', :action => 'showcomment' , :id =>article, :remote => true ,:class=>'show_comment' %></td>
```

My controller action where this request is handled is like this

```
def showcomment
   @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
   @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js{ render :nothing => true }
    end
end
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to try and expand on the other answers a little bit.

In rails when you add `:remote => true` to  a link it essentially takes care of the first part of a jquery ajax call. That's why you don't need `bind.(ajax:success, function(){ #
do stuff here });`

This is a typical jquery ajax call

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  type: "POST"
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

Rails takes care of the first part, up to the `.done` callback. So anything in your javascript erb template is put in the callback like this

```
.done(function() {
  #your showcomments.js.erb file is inserted here
});
```

To render the showcomments.js.erb template from the controller just do this

```
def showcomment
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

You don't need anything after format.js because the default rails action at that point is to render a js template with the same name as the action, in this case it's `showcomment.js.erb`.

Now you know when that link is clicked it will go straight to rendering that `showcomment` template , and any javascript in there will be run instantly. Rails makes using ajax very simple. I hope that helps.

Comment: Doug, can you have js.erb response + firing ajax:success in another plain js file as well? I'm trying to integrate fullcalendar and I'm using js.erb for server side error rendering, but would keep the fullcalendar code in the events.js.

Answer (score 2):

change showcomment to this:

```
def showcomment
   @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
   @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    respond_to { |format| format.js }
end
```

In showcomments.js.erb  you can access both objects `@article` and `@comment`.
A sample use is as below:

```
$('#yourdiv').html('<%= @article.name %>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You render nothing when responding to js format. So code in `showcomments.js.erb` isn't evaluated. Remove `{ render :nothing => true }` in controller and do whatever you want in `showcomments.js.erb`. BTW you don't need `ajax:success` event. It is the end of request already.

*showcomments.js.erb*

```
$('.show_comment').closest('tr').html("<%= # you may render partial here or whatever %>");
```