# jQuery: Adding appropriate structure to DOM (Rails 4)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I've got a `notification` Model of which I am listing all the notifications from a user.

Additionally I've got a notification partial which contains the structure of one single notification.

I now want to display that notification partial, when someone clicks on one listed notification.

Fortunately it is important that that notification gets displayed, the user clicked on previously.

**My Code:**

*View (Haml)*

```
- if current_user.ordered_notifications.any?
    - if current_user.ordered_notifications.unread.exists?
        #notifications.amount
            = render 'notifications'
    - else
        #notifications
            = render 'notifications'
- else
    #notifications
        %i.fa.fa-bell
        .dropdown-content.dd-notifications.left
            .box
                .all
                    %p.smaller.bold.pointer.notifications-popup all notifications
.notification-view
```

*_notification (haml)*

```
= @notification.title #what code is supposed to be here in order to display the correct notification?
```

*_notifications (haml)*

```
- current_user.ordered_notifications.limit(3).each do |notification|
    = link_to(update_notifications_user_path(id: notification.id), remote: true) do
        = notification.title
```

*Controller*

```
def update_notifications
    @notification = current_user.ordered_notifications.find(params[:id])
    @notification.read = true
    @notification.save!

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @notification.link }
        format.js # render users/update_notifications.js.erb
    end
end
```

*jQuery*

```
$('.notification-view').remove();
$('.notification-view').append("<%= j render 'notification' %>");
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @Jordan In the code of `_notification`: `#what code is supposed to be here in order to display the correct notification?`

Comment: You can't insert ERB code using Javascript. That's because only your server can read ERB code.

The usual progression is your server loads the view/partial, reads the ERB code, turns it into HTML, *then* sends it to your web browser, and then your web browser runs Javascript.

If you want to use Javascript to make partial views appear and disappear, you might consider using a front-end framework like Angular.js.

Comment: @RobertAKARobin That's completely true, but Rails is doing all that automatically. I've tested it, and it is completely working fine, if I use `current_user.ordered_notifications.first. [...]` instead of `notification. [...]` for example. The point where I am struggling is to take the Object the User clicked on.

Comment: it seems like when you redirect to `@notification.link`, that's hitting a separate REST endpoint that renders the notification show page. But you haven't shown a route. Basically none of your code you've shown is actually rendering the show page.

Comment: @max pleaner Since the format of the respond is ´js´, it is going to render the appropriate `js.erb` file and don't redirect.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824557/ajax-success-callback-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: @max pleaner That looks pretty similar to my case. My question is though, what should I put into the `js.erb` template ( => `_notification` partial) in order to display the Object of which the AJAX Request just got submitted?

Comment: Try referring to the instance variable @notification. But I'm not clear on why you're using a haml page when you say it should be js erb. It turns out the 'success handler' is the content of the js erb, but you dont have any Javascript yet

Comment: @max pleaner The jQuery on the bottom of my posted question is the `js.erb` file. It referres to the partial `_notification` which then is written in haml. Meaning: The 'success handler' adds the partial to the html markup.

Comment: OK I get you now. Did you try putting a debugger call in the jquery? Might be that you need to put the rendered html string in a jquery selector as well

Comment: @max pleaner I've tested it and everything works. I am able to use that partial to render a specific notification - as mentioned in the comments above. (`current_user.ordered_notifications.first. [...]` instead of `notification. [...]`) I still can't figure out a way to access the notification the user clicked on in the first place. Is there a way to pass the `id` through and use it back in the jQuery?